# Can "guarantee" be used in a negative context?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, negation, connotation

Is the usage of the word 'Guarantee' correct in a negative context? E.g.: "Living in a high landslide hazard zone is no guarantee that a landslide will affect your home." It seems wrong to use the word 'guarantee' here; but what is the alternative word? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did your favourite dictionaries and search engines leave unsaid, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think “guarantee” can do the job, but perhaps if you rephrased the sentence it would be more clear: “Just because a home is in an area classified on a map as being highly susceptible to landslides doesn’t guarantee its destruction.   In fact, ‘high susceptibility’ only means that the expected incidence of a landslide is st least 15% .”

While “guaranty” usually describes a surety relationship or the promise of a vendor to compensate a buyer if the goods or services fail to meet a standard, the word is used negatively:  “If you don’t get that report done and on my desk by Monday, I guarantee you won’t be working here on Tuesday!”

I couldn’t find much formal support for using the word as a substitute for “assure” (it is a meaning included in the OED,  but not with an example), but I think everyone would understand it.  Unless this is for a formal audience, I think it works.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, 'guarantee' *does* seem rather incongruous.

I'd use **entail** in a formal context.

> *entail* verb [with object]
>
> 1 Involve (something) as a necessary or inevitable part or
>   consequence.
>
> *a situation which entails considerable risks*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entail)]

So, 'Living in a high landslide hazard zone does not entail that a landslide will [actually] affect your[/*your*] home.'

Less formally, 'Living in a high landslide hazard zone does not mean that *your* home is certain to be affected by a landslide.'